# Вычитание разных типов указателей в С/C++

Tags: массивы, указатели, стек

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int ia[10];
    int ib[10];
    int * pia = ia;
    int * pib = ib;
    cout << (pib - pia) << endl; /* тут выведет на экран 12, почему не 10? */

    double da[10];
    double db[10];
    double * pda = da;
    double * pdb = db;
    cout << (pdb - pda) << endl; /* а тут 10, как и должно быть */

    return 0;
}
```

Я всегда думал, что вычитание указателей одного типа даст кол-во элементов меж ними,
    но в данном случае с `int` не так. Почему?

Почему, кстати, нельзя вычитать разные типы указателей и выводить кол-во байт между ними?

И последний вопрос. Как я знаю, максимальные адреса находятся в начале стека,
    а конец в сегменте кода, сам стек растёт сверху вниз, т.е. в порядке уменьшения адресов,
    тогда почему если объявить на стеке лок. перемен. `int a;int b;`
    то их адреса будут такими: `&a < &b`, а не наоборот?

Comment: Результат операций `pib-pia`, `pdb-pda` неопределен, может зависеть от компилятора, опций оптимизации и фазы луны.

Comment: разве это так?
можно открыть первую страницу в гугле о вычитание указателей и прочитать, что
Вычитание двух указателей определяет, сколько переменных данного типа размещается между указанными ячейками. Эти операции применимы только к указателям одного типа и имеют смысл в основном со структурными типами данных, например с массивами.

Comment: С чего Вы взяли, что если объявляете два массива подряд, это означает, что они находятся непосредственно друг за другом в памяти? Это не определено стандартном, значит разработчики компилятора могу поступить так, как им угодно, это даже может зависеть от флажков оптимизации. Например попробуйте сделать release сборку.

Comment: @David лучше открыть учебник, и почитать про арифметику указателей.

Comment: Выделите malloc'ом кусок памяти в 20 байт - для указателя на int, и для указателя на char. В первый массив сможем поместить 5 элементов (при условии sizeof(int) = 4 ), во второй - 20 элементов (при условии sizeof(char) = 1). Как видите, при одном и том же объеме выделенной пямяти имеем разное количество элементов. Так как же мы можем здесь вычитать ?

Comment: @andy.37, и, пожалуй, фаза Луны - ключевой фактор ))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компилятор реализует некоторый стандарт С/С++, который определяет правила и поведение. Все, что явно не прописано в этом стандарте, реализуется на усмотрение разработчика компилятора.

Вы сравниваете два разных массива. Вычитание их указателей даст количество элементов между двумя ячейками памяти. Но в стандарте нигде не сказано, что при объявлении двух разных массивов в коде друг за другом, они так же будут находится в памяти друг за другом. Следовательно не факт, что эти адреса идут друг за другом в строгом порядке и туда не вклинится что-то еще, потому получаем UB. Вы получаете правильное значение, расстояние в типах между адресами, но неправильно считаете адреса рядом находящимися.

Вычитать разные типы указателей не имеет смысла, это просто усложняет архитектуру и почти нигде не используется. Если уж хочется, всегда можно посчитать количество элементов и получить разность их sizeof. В язык просто так ничего не добавляется, каждый элемент должен нести осознанную полезность.

По третьему вопросу опять же, никто не гарантируем порядок размещения элементов в стеке, это определяет разработчик компилятора. Поэтому иногда ловушки кроются там, где Вы получаете один и тот же результат и думаете, что это поведение будет всегда и везде одинаково.

Comment: Как получение разницы указателей (с неопределенным значением) приводит к UB?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, Вы никогда не сможете точно сказать, какой результат получите в результате подобного вычитания указателей двух разных несвязанных переменных. Компилятор их может переставить каким угодно образом в адресном пространстве, поскольку это не регламентировано. Это имеет смысл для операций внутри массивов и других элементов, где порядок гарантируется, но не в данном случае.

Comment: Окей, т.е. такой код: `int a; int b = a;` по вашем UB? Ведь здесь значение `a` может быть каким угодно. И если UB, то компилятор имеет право отправить ракеты на луну? Т.е. хочу сказать, что в самой операции вычитания нет UB, другое дело если потом использовать этот результат для доступа к памяти.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, тогда определитесь, мы говорим о результате присваивания `a == b` или о самом значении в памяти? Значение в памяти определенно будет UB. Получение разницы указателей подобным образом как в вопросе приводит к UB. Приравнивание одного значения другому является строго определенным поведением. И да, в случае операций с UB может состояться и запуск ракеты на луну, если Вы разрабатываете софт для этого на С/C++))

Comment: Ссылку на стандарт пожалуйста, что операция вычитания над значениями, определяемыми реализацией, являются UB. Ну и немного поменяю тогда пример: `int a; int b = a - 1;` - добавилось операция вычитания. Теперь UB по вашему?

Comment: Или может вы путаете неопределенность получаемого значения и UB?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian читайте внимательно, что Вам пишут! Еще раз, я говорю об **результате вычитания адресов и указателей** разных переменных при их размещении в памяти компилятором. Те примеры, которые Вы мне приводите, не имеют никакой связи и смысла в контексте моего ответа.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49346/discussion-between-vladimir-gamalian-and-alex-krass).

Comment: *"Окей, т.е. такой код: int a; int b = a; по вашем UB?"* - да, это UB. В debian из-за похожего кода возникла серьезная уязвимость.

Answer (score 3):

Согласен с предыдущими ораторами :) на счет UB, 100% - зависит от ряда факторов. В том числе и от выравнивания:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int ia[10];
    int ib[10];
    int * pia = ia;
    int * pib = ib;
    cout << __alignof__(ia) << endl; // 4 на ideone (C++14)

    double da[10];
    double db[10];
    double * pda = da;
    double * pdb = db;
    cout << __alignof__(da) << endl; // 8 на ideone (C++14)

    return 0;
}
```

@Vladimir Gamalian, лови:

Кусок из 5.7 ISO/IEC 14882, Third edition 2011-09-01

5. When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type
   of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array is
   large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the difference of
   the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integral expression. In other words, if
   the expression P points to the i-th element of an array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P))
   and (P)-N (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i + n-th and i − n-th elements of the array
   object, provided they exist. Moreover, if the expression P points to the last element of an array object,
   the expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object, and if the expression Q points
   one past the last element of an array object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array
   object. If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past
   the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is
   undefined.
6. When two pointers to elements of the same array object are subtracted, the result is the difference of the
   subscripts of the two array elements. The type of the result is an implementation-defined signed integral
   type; this type shall be the same type that is defined as std::ptrdiff_t in the  header (18.2). As
   with any other arithmetic overflow, if the result does not fit in the space provided, the behavior is undefined.
   In other words, if the expressions P and Q point to, respectively, the i-th and j-th elements of an array object,
   the expression (P)-(Q) has the value i − j provided the value fits in an object of type std::ptrdiff_t.
   Moreover, if the expression P points either to an element of an array object or one past the last element of
   an array object, and the expression Q points to the last element of the same array object, the expression
   ((Q)+1)-(P) has the same value as ((Q)-(P))+1 and as -((P)-((Q)+1)), and has the value zero if the
   expression P points one past the last element of the array object, even though the expression (Q)+1 does not
   point to an element of the array object. **Unless both pointers** point to elements of **the same** array object, or one past the last element of the array object, **the behavior is undefined**.82
7. If the value 0 is added to or subtracted from a pointer value, the result compares equal to the original pointer value. If two pointers point to the same object or both point one past the end of the same array or both are null, and the two pointers are subtracted, the result compares equal to the value 0 converted to the type std::ptrdiff_t.

Comment: В чем UB? Вычитание указателей даст разницу в их значениях и это вполне определенное поведение.

Comment: Но это не означает разницу в размерах последовательно прописанных переменных в коде. Это означает на сколько один адрес находится далеко от другого, и не более. И способ выравнивания - одна из причин.

Comment: Конечно не означает. Но как из этого следует, что это udnefined behavior?

Comment: Оптимизатор вправе сделать не так как вы полагаете. Может вообще переменную выкинуть, если она не используется. А раз это действие на откупе реализации - значит UB.

Comment: Тогда, боюсь, вы не понимаете смысла термина UB.

Comment: А что в неопределенном поведении может быть непонятного? ТС надеется получить разницу адресов как размерность массива. Но это не всегда так - читаем "неопределено".

Comment: @Majestio, ваш оппонент просто придирается к разнице между "является UB" и "может привести к UB"...

Comment: Да ланна - вон я кусок стандарта привел, там выделил нужное. Пусть минусует, если ему для души это нужно)))

Comment: Ну вот, теперь все на свои места встало. Со ссылкой на стандарт всегда веселей )

Answer (score 2):

Цитата из K&R

> К числу разрешенных операций с указателями относятся:
>
> - присваивание указателей одного типа
> - сложение и вычитание указателя и целого числа
> - вычитание или сравнение указателей, **указывающих на один и тот же массив данных**
> - присваивание нуля или сравнение с ним
>
> все остальные операции являются ошибками и не разрешены.

Т.е. в Вашей программе - UB, и формально, она имеет право сделать что угодно, вплоть до форматирования жесткого диска. В реальности, конечно, ничего страшного не произойдет, пока Вы не пытаетесь использовать результат запрещенной операции для любого доступа к памяти.

Comment: Тот ответ, которого я ждал ) Можете ссылкой на стандарт дополнить?

Comment: В реальности, конечно, ничего страшного не произойдет, *пока Вы не пытаетесь использовать результат запрещенной операции для любого доступа к памяти* - или не напишут эвристику для оптимизации, опирающуюся на вычитание указателей :)

Answer (score 0):

Вы сейчас углубились в область поведения, определяемого реализацией. А ваши попытки измерять размер массивов через вычитание указателей - и вовсе UB.

Тот факт, что стек растет "вниз", означает всего лишь, что каждый вложенный фрейм стека имеет адрес меньше чем предыдущий. Но внутри фрейма стека компилятор может выделять память для локальных переменных как угодно.

В вашем случае, скорее всего, компилятор выровнял массивы по границе, кратной 128 бит (16 байт). Но мог и засунуть, к примеру, между двумя массивами какой-нибудь указатель.

Вычитать указатели разных типов нельзя потому что вычитание указателей дает количество элементов между ними - а какой из двух типов элементов брать базовым? Если же вам нужна разница в байтах - всегда можно привести указатели к указателю на char:

```
cout << (reinterpret_cast<char*>(pda) - reinterpret_cast<char*>(pia)) << endl;
```

Comment: а чем моя попытка измерить размер массива вычетом указателей UB?

Comment: @David точно не помню. Может, кто-нибудь поправит.

Comment: @David, если быть точным, пока вы не пытаетесь использовать результат `pdb-pda` для обращения к памяти - это безопасно (просто произвольное целое число). А использование - равносильно доступу к произвольному адресу, типа `*(int*)(rand()) = 10;` Компилятор имеет полное право вовсе переставить местами Ваши массивы из соображений оптимизации.